# ネットワークのセグメントが被っているとは？

Tags: network

インフラ運用初心者です。
基礎的なことかもしれないので、大変恐縮なのですが、ネットワークでセグメントが被っているとはどこを見れば判断できるのでしょうか。

セグメントとは何かしらをまとめたグループであることは理解してます。
ただ、被っているかどうかの判断が出来ず困っています。

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: オイラ達 10BASE-5 の頃からネットワーク使ってる人にとって「セグメント」はコリジョンドメインのことだけど、今時の人にとってはブロードキャストドメインのことかもしれないし、あなたと読者間で用語の意味に合意がないと回答つかないと思う。ついてもあなたのほうが理解できないかも。コリジョンドメインがかぶるという表現は限りなく意味がなさそうだし。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。承知致しました。

Comment: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers にもありますが「ありがとう」だけのコメントは不要です。この質問の場合、あいまいであって読者で解釈が異なるであろう単語「セグメント」を、もうちょっと厳密な専門用語に書き換えていただくと、あなたの期待する回答が得られるかもしれません。ご検討ください。